# Customize AJAX URL

Tags: wicket, wicket-1.5, wicket-1.6

On one of our pages we have added a `AbstractAjaxTimerBehavior` (to add potential new items to a `Repeatingview`). The AJAX call that is executed is the following:

```
https://.../home/?0-1.IBehaviorListener.0-filteredContentHandler&random=0.38872813899070024
```

However, because of the random part this URL is not static. I'm also not sure if `?0-1` is always the same.

Is there a way in Wicket 1.5 or Wicket 6 (which we might upgrade to) to set a static URL for a certain call?

---

*(The reason for this requirement is to provide this URL to Siteminder (SSO) so that the SSO session is ignoring these URL's to keep the SSO session alive).*

Comment: You need to make the link stateless. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10582601/how-can-i-make-wickets-ajaxlink-stateless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question:

```
public class AjaxTimerBehaviorMapper extends AbstractComponentMapper {

    private final IRequestMapper wrappedMapper;

    private final String prefix;

    /**
     * @param rootRequestMapper
     */
    public AjaxTimerBehaviorMapper(IRequestMapper wrappedMapper, String prefix) {
        this.wrappedMapper = wrappedMapper;
        this.prefix = prefix;
    }

    @Override
    public IRequestHandler mapRequest(Request request) {
        Url url = request.getUrl();
        if (url.getSegments().size() >= 1 && url.getSegments().get(0).equals(this.prefix)) {
            url.removeLeadingSegments(1);
        }
        return this.wrappedMapper.mapRequest(request.cloneWithUrl(url));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCompatibilityScore(Request request) {
        return this.wrappedMapper.getCompatibilityScore(request);
    }

    @Override
    public Url mapHandler(IRequestHandler requestHandler) {
        Url url = this.wrappedMapper.mapHandler(requestHandler);
        if (requestHandler instanceof ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler) {
            ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler listenerInterfaceRequestHandler = (ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler) requestHandler;

            RequestListenerInterface requestListenerInterface = listenerInterfaceRequestHandler.getListenerInterface();
            if (requestListenerInterface != null) {
                Class<? extends IRequestListener> listenerInterfaceClass = requestListenerInterface.getListenerInterfaceClass();
                if (IBehaviorListener.class.isAssignableFrom(listenerInterfaceClass)) {
                    IRequestableComponent requestableComponent = listenerInterfaceRequestHandler.getComponent();
                    if (requestableComponent != null) {
                        Integer behaviorIndex = listenerInterfaceRequestHandler.getBehaviorIndex();
                        Behavior behavior = requestableComponent.getBehaviorById(behaviorIndex);
                        if (behavior != null) {
                            if (AbstractAjaxTimerBehavior.class.isAssignableFrom(behavior.getClass())
                                || CustomAbstractAjaxTimerBehavior.class.isAssignableFrom(behavior.getClass())) {
                                url.prependLeadingSegments(newArrayList(this.prefix));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return url;
    }
}
```

This way wicket will use the given fixed prefix in the url.